# Business class fully booked!

Tags: bookings, seating, business-travel

I am planning to fly our from YYZ to DEL (Depart 15th December, Return- 15th Janaury) on a round trip ticket with Etihad on business class. However, the problem is that the business class section is completely booked. How likely is the case that the business class section is going to have free seats as the departing date approaches. Has anyone experienced such an issue? Help is much appreciated.
Thanks,

Comment: Is it just one leg where there's no availability, or all legs? And is it "cabin full", or "deeply discounted business class fare bucket Z is fully booked"?

Comment: A quick search just on kayak for these days and route shows me there's still tickets available -- going out you can do YYZ-DUB-AUH-DEL and coming back there's DEL-AUH-YYZ but the two stops route is only 10 minutes longer altogether and honestly 22:10 vs 22:20 just doesn't matter. Of course, you might've other reasons not wanting to take this, just sayin'.

Answer (score 5):

Sold out usually means sold out.

Airlines do not hold back seats during the sales process.  Your best hope is that there are some seats in a code share block held by another airline. You should check with the other airlines that sell the flight(s) as a code share to see if they can sell you a business class ticket on that routing.

Otherwise your only hope is that someone cancels their current booking.

Comment: This is not necessarily the case: particularly for business class, tickets are often flexible and are moved or cancelled quite frequently.  If you use a bricks & mortar travel agent, they should be able to book you on an alternate date and get you waitlisted on your flights of choice.

Comment: @jpatokal - I specifically said that his only hope is that someone cancels, so how is my answer "not neccesarily the case".  When the flight is shown as sold out, it is sold out until someone cancels their booking on that flight.

Comment: Indeed, the cabin is probably heavily overbooked if they have closed the inventory already

Comment: @Tom I don't think we're disagreeing here, but your post sounds like cancelling is a rare and unusual thing, when it's actually fairly common in biz.

Comment: @jpatokal - so I guess I should have said "don't worry someone will cancel" ... ;-)

Comment: @Tom I would still worry, but I wouldn't lose hope just yet!  I've snagged even award seats in "fully booked" business class a few times.